# OpenYoutubeActivity: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError OpenYouTubePlayerActivity

Tags: java, android, android-youtube-api

I am trying to implement Youtube player to my Android app but I have a problem of run it normally. I have next exception:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: OpenYouTubePlayerActivity

Try to find something in Google, saw a lot of similar solutions which are the same as mine but it isn't working. How can I fix it?

This is my piece of code: (openyoutubeactivity.jar and its path has add to my project, different permissions have added and everything was did by official doc of this lib)

```
Intent lVideoIntent = new Intent(null, Uri.parse("ytv://jDgDW8bSdvw"), this, OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.class);
    startActivity(lVideoIntent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to fix it, there was just need to add a signature to the link in the VideoStream file of this library and everything is working like charm!

```
VideoStream.java (Line: 30)
before: mUrl = lArgMap.get("url");
after:  mUrl = lArgMap.get("url") + "&signature=" + lArgMap.get("sig");
```

Comment: I am not sure where exactly do I make changes for the signature. It is written that changes are to be done at line 30 in VideoStream.java. I am using only the file OpenYouTubePlayerActivity.java here. Somebody please help.

Comment: Its very helpful code.... My problem solved with this small changes... Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 0):

You have to add OpenYouTubePlayerActivity in to your manifest file.

Comment: Yeap, this was done:                                        <activity
            android:name="OpenYouTubePlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation" />

Comment: I have found my mistake(but that is strange a bit due to I had already try this way). So, I had wrong path to OpenYoutubeActivity in the manifest. 

    <activity
        android:name="com.keyes.youtube.OpenYouTubePlayerActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation" />
    <activity

Now I have passed this error and faced with another one - "Sorry, this video cannot be played". As I see on the forum of this project lot of guys cannot run it due to it but no solution is wroten. May be, someone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Oh, in advance, maybe, someone knows when will be the release of new Youtube Android Player exactly? I heart only that it will soon in future months(june`s news). Either, somebody has a demo library?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by changing the project target from `8 to 10`from `project.properties` file.. But finally ended with "Can't play this video" error.